# Hide a Url address bar on scroll in Flutter Web (Mobile)

Tags: flutter, mobile, uiscrollview, flutterflow

I am trying to achieve a default behavior of the mobile browser: hide address url bar on scroll down. But in flutter it seems to be broken for some reason.

I am facing the same problem explained here [text](https://github.com/FlutterFlow/flutterflow-issues/issues/1297)

If there is any native solution or some kind of  workaround I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.